# Need to configure liquidsoap for transcoding

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, icecast, liquidsoap

I'm trying to transcode stream with liquid and output to icecast2
Below is my config taken from official website http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/cookbook.html

```
# Input the stream,
# from an Icecast server or any other source
url = "http://www.protonradio.com:8000/schedule.m3u"
input = mksafe(input.http(url))

# First transcoder: MP3 32 kbps
# We also degrade the samplerate, and encode in mono
# Accordingly, a mono conversion is performed on the input stream
output.icecast(
  %mp3(bitrate=32, samplerate=22050, stereo=false),
  mount="/your-stream-32.mp3",
  host="streaming.example.com", port=8000, password="xxx",
  mean(input))
```

When I try to run it with ./radio.liq
I get this error:

```
root@Ubuntu:/etc/liquidsoap# ./radio.liq
./radio.liq: line 4: url: command not found
./radio.liq: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./radio.liq: line 5: `input = mksafe(input.http(url))'
root@Ubuntu:/etc/liquidsoap#
```

Here's what happens when I run with this command:

```
root@Ubuntu:/etc/liquidsoap# liquidsoap radio2.liq
init: security exit, root euid (user).
root@Ubuntu:/etc/liquidsoap#
```

Buffer errors with this stream url http://46.21.106.168:80

```
2016/09/30 15:57:17 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2016/09/30 15:57:20 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s.
2016/09/30 15:57:26 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s.
2016/09/30 15:57:37 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.01s.
2016/09/30 15:57:44 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s.
2016/09/30 15:58:11 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s.
2016/09/30 15:58:47 [http_4756:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start liquidsoap interpreter and feed your script to it like this:

`liquidsoap radio.liq`

In your example you start the script from the command line directly and it goes to shell (bash), not liquidsoap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
So, I tried running it with above command and now I get this error:
`code`
root@Ubuntu-VM:/etc/liquidsoap# liquidsoap radio.liq
Line 9, char 80 before ":": Parse error!
root@Ubuntu-VM:/etc/liquidsoap#
`code`

Comment: Here's my config:
`code`
# Input the stream,
# from an Icecast server or any other source
# url = "http://www.protonradio.com:8000/schedule.m3u"
#liveset = mksafe(input.http("http://www.protonradio.com:8000/schedule.m3u")) 
#liveset = rewrite_metadata([("artist", "Santiago Saa"),("title", "120 minutest Live")], liveset) 
#source = single "audiofile.mp3"
#live = input.http "http://www.protonradio.com:8000/schedule.m3u" 
radio = (input.http(max=30.0, "http://www.protonradio.com:8000/schedule.m3u")):source(1,0,0))

Comment: # Second transcoder : MP3 64 kbps
output.icecast(
  %mp3(bitrate=64), 
  mount="/your-stream-64.mp3",
  host="localhost", port=8000, password="xxxxxxx",
  input)
`code`


It looks like its complaing about :source(1,0,0))
?

Comment: Please add your new config to the original post. It is impossible to read it w/o line breaks.

Comment: Sorry about that. Not sure what happened but since then I did a reboot and now I'm getting different error output. Its in original post.
Seems like root cannot run that?

Comment: Correct, liquidsoap can not be run as root. Add another system user, log in and start liquidsoap with another user privileges.

Comment: Thank you! Finally got to work with one exception. In log file I'm getting buffer errors and they are in the original post. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check CPU usage on your machine, maybe it is not enough CPU to transcode the stream.

Comment: This is on a dedicated server with Xeon CPU and 32GB RAM so I don't this that's the problem. Server just has few of websites with no high traffic.

Comment: Then it may be something else, try googling your error message - I saw some forum and mail list discussions about that.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I did already but it briefly flashes this message:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the comments of Alexeys answer.

Your script did not run because you did not tell the script what application to run it with. On windows the file extension (.exe or .txt or .doc) is used to distinguish which application to open. On Unix the first line known as the "sha bang" tells the OS which application must run this file.

So if you first check where your liquidsoap is installed with:

```
which liquidsoap
```

Then add the response path to your scripts first line like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
```

Unix will now know which application to open it with.

On your second observation(not issue), the Overrun is seen because you are fetching a stream from a Icecast server using http. The Icecast sever is generally configured to "burst" some data to you on connection (normally for players to fill their buffers). Anyhow, the buffer used in the input.http command is too small for this sudden burst of data and therefore liquidsoap throws a overflow exception. To fix this, increase the max buffer.

```
input = mksafe(input.http(url,buffer=2.,max=120.))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain!

I did looked at the logs and its so random when "Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s." occurs. I added your suggestion and will report back after few days if that fixed it.

Comment: Ok, so after few days of testing I'm not seeing "Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.00s" in logs but now I see "Switch to safe_blank with forgetful transition." and after searching online it appears to be network lag causing the internal buffer to empty. I don not have control over source stream so for now I'm calling it good. Thanks for your help!